Is it possible to solve this non-linear integer programming problem with Mathematica?
I am solving the following non-linear integer programming problem (see "The Kvant", 2024, # 9, p. 20) in 14.1 on Windows

The sequence of natural
numbers $a_n, n=1 , \dots , 100$, is such that $a_1 = 1$ and for
each natural $ n = 1, 2, \dots, 100$,
the number $(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)\left(\frac 1 {a_1}+ \frac 1 {a_2} +\cdots+ \frac 1 {a_n} \right)$
is an integer. What is the largest value that $a_{100}$ can take?

Its optimal solution is not obvious as the result of
n = 3;
NMaximize[ Flatten[{a[n], a[1] == 1, Table[Sum[a[k], {k, 1, s}]*Sum[1/a[k], {k, 1, s}] == 
b[s], {s, 2,  n}], Table[a[k], {k, 2, n}] \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
Table[b[s], {s, 2, n}] \[Element] PositiveIntegers}], 
Union[Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}], Table[b[s], {s, 2, n}]]]


{2.,{a[1]->1.,a[2]->1,a[3]->2,b[2]->4,b[3]->10}}

demonstrates.
I face  difficulties, trying to solve even a simplified problem.
   n = 16;
NMaximize[ Flatten[{a[n], a[1] == 1, Table[Sum[a[k], {k, 1, s}]*Sum[1/a[k], {k, 1, s}] == 
b[s], {s, 2,  n}], Table[a[k], {k, 2, n}] \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
Table[b[s], {s, 2, n}] \[Element] PositiveIntegers}], 
Union[Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}], Table[b[s], {s, 2, n}]]]


NMaximize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001:
{(1/a[1]+1/a[2]) (a[1]+a[2])-b[2]==0,<<13>>,(1/a[1]+1/a[2]+1/a[3]+1/a[4]+1/a[5]+1/a[6]+1/a[7]+1/a[8]+
1/a[9]+1/a[10]+1/a[11]+1/a[12]+1/a[13]+1/a[14]+1/a[15]+1/a[16]) (a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+a[4]+a[5]+a[6]+a[7]+a[8]+
a[9]+a[10]+a[11]+a[12]+a[13]+a[14]+a[15]+a[16])-b[16]==0}.
{1., {a[1] -> 1., a[2] -> 2, a[3] -> 2, a[4] -> 2, a[5] -> 2,  a[6] -> 2, a[7] -> 2, a[8] -> 2, a[9] -> 2, a[10] -> 2, a[11] -> 2,  a[12] -> 2, a[13] -> 2, a[14] -> 2, a[15] -> 2, a[16] -> 1,  b[2] -> 3, b[3] -> 3, b[4] -> 4, b[5] -> 5, b[6] -> 1, b[7] -> 2,  b[8] -> 11, b[9] -> 1, b[10] -> 11, b[11] -> 10, b[12] -> 1,  b[13] -> 9, b[14] -> 3, b[15] -> 11, b[16] -> 89}}

The same warning with Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 100} and {2., {a[1] -> 1., a[2] -> 2, a[3] -> 2, a[4] -> 2, a[5] -> 2,  a[6] -> 2, a[7] -> 2, a[8] -> 2, a[9] -> 2, a[10] -> 2, a[11] -> 2,  a[12] -> 2, a[13] -> 1, a[14] -> 1, a[15] -> 2, a[16] -> 2,  b[2] -> 1, b[3] -> 3, b[4] -> 3, b[5] -> 3, b[6] -> 3, b[7] -> 3,  b[8] -> 3, b[9] -> 2, b[10] -> 2, b[11] -> 2, b[12] -> 2,  b[13] -> 3, b[14] -> 2, b[15] -> 3, b[16] -> 2}}.
The same warning with Method -> "NelderMead" and
{1., {a[1] -> 1., a[2] -> 1, a[3] -> 1, a[4] -> 1, a[5] -> 1,  a[6] -> 1, a[7] -> 1, a[8] -> 1, a[9] -> 1, a[10] -> 1, a[11] -> 1,  a[12] -> 1, a[13] -> 1, a[14] -> 1, a[15] -> 1, a[16] -> 1,  b[2] -> 1, b[3] -> 1, b[4] -> 1, b[5] -> 1, b[6] -> 1, b[7] -> 1,  b[8] -> 1, b[9] -> 1, b[10] -> 1, b[11] -> 1, b[12] -> 1,  b[13] -> 1, b[14] -> 1, b[15] -> 1, b[16] -> 1}}
The result with Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1,  "SearchPoints" -> 200}] consists of the same warning and
{1., {a[1] -> 1., a[2] -> 3, a[3] -> 3, a[4] -> 1, a[5] -> 1,  a[6] -> 1, a[7] -> 2, a[8] -> 2, a[9] -> 2, a[10] -> 2, a[11] -> 2,  a[12] -> 2, a[13] -> 1, a[14] -> 1, a[15] -> 1, a[16] -> 1,  b[2] -> 10, b[3] -> 1, b[4] -> 32, b[5] -> 60, b[6] -> 55,  b[7] -> 65, b[8] -> 58, b[9] -> 53, b[10] -> 123, b[11] -> 135,  b[12] -> 146, b[13] -> 196, b[14] -> 272, b[15] -> 282,  b[16] -> 329}}.
The result with Method -> "Couenne": "NMaximize::divit: Detected diverging iterates." and the returned input.
The question arises: is it possible to find the optimal solution of the problem under consideration fo n>=16 with Mathematica?

I take it all the intermediate values of the expression have to be an integer as well - otherwise there are infinite number of solutions and there is no maximum of a[100].

I think you can show that at each step you wish to maximize the value of a[n].  With this result I think it follows that a[n] ==2 a[n-1] for n>2.

@micado: Thank you for your guess. Can you ground your claim?

The following is not an answer, but my attempt to make a prediction. This gives a lower bound $a_n\geq 2^{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$.
In[1]:= ClearAll[f, a];
a[1] = 1;
f[n_] := Together[Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}]*Sum[1/a[k], {k, 1, n}]]

In[4]:= f[1]

Out[4]= 1

In[5]:= Apart[f[2] - f[1]]

Out[5]= 1 + 1/a[2] + a[2]

In[6]:= a[2] = 1

Out[6]= 1

In[7]:= Apart[f[3] - f[2]]

Out[7]= 1 + 2/a[3] + 2 a[3]

In[8]:= a[3] = 2

Out[8]= 2

In[9]:= Apart[f[4] - f[3]]

Out[9]= 1 + 4/a[4] + (5 a[4])/2

In[10]:= a[4] = 4

Out[10]= 4

In[11]:= Apart[f[5] - f[4]]

Out[11]= 1 + 8/a[5] + (11 a[5])/4

In[12]:= a[5] = 8

Out[12]= 8

In[13]:= Apart[f[6] - f[5]]

Out[13]= 1 + 16/a[6] + (23 a[6])/8

In[14]:= a[6] = 16

Out[14]= 16

In[15]:= (* Conjecture *)

In[16]:= ClearAll[a];
a[1] = 1;
a[k_Integer /; k >= 2] := 2^(k - 2);

In[19]:= Table[f[k], {k, 1, 100}]

Out[19]= {1, 4, 10, 22, 46, 94, 190, 382, 766, 1534, 3070, 6142, 
12286, 24574, 49150, 98302, 196606, 393214, 786430, 1572862, 3145726, 
6291454, 12582910, 25165822, 50331646, 100663294, 201326590, 
402653182, 805306366, 1610612734, 3221225470, 6442450942, 
12884901886, 25769803774, 51539607550, 103079215102, 206158430206, 
412316860414, 824633720830, 1649267441662, 3298534883326, 
6597069766654, 13194139533310, 26388279066622, 52776558133246, 
105553116266494, 211106232532990, 422212465065982, 844424930131966, 
1688849860263934, 3377699720527870, 6755399441055742, 
13510798882111486, 27021597764222974, 54043195528445950, 
108086391056891902, 216172782113783806, 432345564227567614, 
864691128455135230, 1729382256910270462, 3458764513820540926, 
6917529027641081854, 13835058055282163710, 27670116110564327422, 
55340232221128654846, 110680464442257309694, 221360928884514619390, 
442721857769029238782, 885443715538058477566, 1770887431076116955134, 
3541774862152233910270, 7083549724304467820542, 
14167099448608935641086, 28334198897217871282174, 
56668397794435742564350, 113336795588871485128702, 
226673591177742970257406, 453347182355485940514814, 
906694364710971881029630, 1813388729421943762059262, 
3626777458843887524118526, 7253554917687775048237054, 
14507109835375550096474110, 29014219670751100192948222, 
58028439341502200385896446, 116056878683004400771792894, 
232113757366008801543585790, 464227514732017603087171582, 
928455029464035206174343166, 1856910058928070412348686334, 
3713820117856140824697372670, 7427640235712281649394745342, 
14855280471424563298789490686, 29710560942849126597578981374, 
59421121885698253195157962750, 118842243771396506390315925502, 
237684487542793012780631851006, 475368975085586025561263702014, 
950737950171172051122527404030, 1901475900342344102245054808062}


Thank you for your Interesting work. I am out of MMA some time. I'll try to give my response as soon as possible.

+1. Sure unexpected. It would be interesting to take a solution found by you as the initial one for NMaximize.

This recursively solves for maximum value of a[n]. As alluded to by @mikado it can shown by induction that $a_n=2^{n-2}$ for $n>=2$, as alluded to by A. Kato answer.
At each step the maximum solution that produces integer  for expression is found.
f[u_] := Total[u] Total[1/u] // Expand;
aa[1] := 1;
aa[n_] := 
  aa[n] = Max[
    a[n] /. Solve[{w[n] == 
        f[{1}~Join~Table[aa[j], {j, 2, n - 1}]~Join~{a[n]}], 
       a[n] > 0}, {w[n], a[n]}, Integers]];
s = aa[100]
s == 2^98


For those interested

Comment: as @ngc5139 noted for this to be well posed requires integers at every step.
Seasons greetings to all.

"I will not be responding to comments" ??? What?

@ngc5139 I have removed qualifier but it is my intention to only respond (if I can) to comments relevant to the answer.Omega Centauri is a nice globular cluster.
